# Hiding specific HTML table cells with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have found other questions through which I learned how to hide the first row and the (first row's) first cell using;

```
$('table#truetable tr:first').hide();
```

and

```
$('table#truetable td:first').hide();
```

But what if I want to hide for example the first cell of the second row using this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#truetable tr:eq(1) td:first').hide();
```

[`:eq` docs](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

```
jQuery(':eq(index)')
```

> **index**
>   Zero-based index of the element to match.

Comment: It's worth mentioning (I was going to post a separate answer, but didn't seem to be worth the unnecessary repetition) that with `hide()` it [can disturb the visual presentation of the table](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WGSDb/), so might be better using [`addClass()`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WGSDb/1/) or [`css()`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WGSDb/2/) to achieve the required result.

Comment: @DavidThomas. +1. An excellent comment. But maybe this is the output the OP actually wants.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('table#truetable tr:eq(1) td:first-child').hide();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you use `:eq` and `:first-child`? If you already use `:eq` what don't you use it again?

Answer (score 0):

theres a css selector for this:

```
:nth-child(N)
```

N is the index of the child +1 in the selection